# Chrome developer tools to locate invoked javascript function

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

In http://themify.me/

When scroll to the portion as the following image, the 3 icons will be animated up. 
I am interested to know what js file is trigerring.
How should I use chrome developer tools to locate it?

[image]

Comment: Set a DOM modification breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [keyframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) animation declared as a `-webkit-animation-name` property:

```css
li.animate-up {
-webkit-animation-name: flyInBottom;
}
```

Here's the implementation:

```css
@keyframes flyInBottom {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 200px);
        -ms-transform: translate(0px, 200px);
        transform: translate(0px, 200px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    }
}
```

I found it by simply clicking `Inspect element` and then following CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1):

The animation is getting triggered using CSS animation. To locate the CSS properties, you can use chrome developer tools[image]. Note the magnifier icon in top left corner. Just click that and move mouse over the area you desire to inspect. In this case the element is `li` and CSS class applied to it is `animate-up`. You will notice that on the right side you will see styles section with the list of CSS styles applied for the given element.[image] Just click on the style.css link and you will see entire stylesheet. Here you will find definition for

```
.slide-up.animated li.animate-up {
-webkit-animation-name: flyInBottom;
animation-name: flyInBottom;
}
```

Just scroll few blocks and you will find animation definition for flyInBottom.

```
@-webkit-keyframes flyInBottom {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 200px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 200px);
    transform: translate(0px, 200px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
}
}
```